# Incomplete Code Coverage in Go Due to Unimported Packages

Tags: go

I am in the process of discovering the Go language. I tried to create a project structure that resembles a Python package:

```
-src:
|- main.go
|- services:
  |- pipeline.go
|- core:
  |- utils.go
-test:
|- pipeline_test.go
-go.mod
```

However, I am facing a problem trying to calculate code coverage. I ran the command:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out -covermode=atomic ./tests/...
```

But this only calculates coverage for imported files, i.e., packages imported in the test files. Packages not imported in tests such as “main” and “core” are not being taken into account. In Python, all files are taken into account. So, my question is whether there is a solution to scan all files even if they are not imported in the test files.

Comment: First, don't structure your project like python (there's no `go.mod` here, so I'm not sure how this is supposed to work together). Also, see https://go.dev/blog/integration-test-coverage

Comment: Put everything into one package. Go isn't Python; several things are done differently.

Comment: That is correct. My project structure is simply collecting all tests in a "tests" folder, which is not specific to Python or any other language.

Comment: Any test specific to a package is expected to be contained within that package. If you don't want to do that you are essentially creating integration tests. It is specific to the language, because different language tools expect different structures, and Go expects unit tests to live within their packages.

Comment: Why would you get coverage on code not used by the tests?!

Comment: "My project structure is simply collecting all tests in a "tests" folder, which is not specific to Python or any other language" True. And in Go the test should (read "must") be in the same folder. This is specific to Go.

Comment: @JimB Imagine that we are creating tests for our project, and we forget to include a package. The coverage will appear to be 100%, but it does not take into account the effects of this forgotten package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think others have probably already provided some context in the comments, but let me tell you explicitly.

In Go, you do not get code coverage results for packages you don't test. This is actually a useful feature because it means your coverage result is more predictive of whether or not you're actually testing your code. In other languages, such as C# or Python, all modules in a package are included in coverage, which can result in artificially low numbers since boilerplate code typically doesn't need to be covered by unit tests and is normally handled by integration tests. In go, this code is excluded unless you add tests for it explicitly. This also provides an implicit guide to you, the developer: if you're adding tests to your main module, then you should probably split that code into a package that you can add tests for.

Also, about your project structure, you shouldn't apply Pythonic assumptions to Go. Put your tests in the same package as the code those tests should cover. The test code won't be included when the code is imported by doing `go get` so there's no reason to have a separate package for tests only. Of course, you can still do that if you have test utilities or test support objects that you do want to include with your other code, but in general you should keep test code where it's supposed to run.

In the example you provided, `pipeline_test.go` should be moved to `pipeline.go`. Also, if you have code you want covered in `utils`, then you should add a `utils_test.go` file as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I understand everything now. It's very informative for me. I thank you again.

Comment: @zekrisidimohamedhicham No problem at all. It's always hard going from one language to another. Good luck with your Go programming